# Node.js freeze after a few requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I am trying around with nodejs and socket.io

But my application refuses to work after a few requests. It takes a while and after some time it starts working again.

Here is the code for the nodejs-server, where i expect the issue.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('db.sqlite');
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/app/index.html");
});
router.get('/sample', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/app/sample.html");
});
router.post('/api/error', function (req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
    data.date = Date();
    io.emit('error', JSON.stringify(data));
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a client connected');
});

app.use('', router);
app.use(express.static('app'));
app.use('/static', express.static('node_modules'));

// START THE SERVER
server.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

The applikation is for monitoring errors in a full webstack.

Comment: Any code related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: The handler for `POST /api/error` isn't ending the request (by sending back a response).

Comment: @robertklep wow awesome. thats the error :) you are great.

Answer (score 5):

The handler for `POST /api/error` isn't sending back a response, so the client will continue to wait. At some point, it may decide not to open any more connections to the server until the previous ones have been answered (or have timed out).

You can just send back a 200 response:

```
router.post('/api/error', function (req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
    data.date = Date();
    io.emit('error', JSON.stringify(data));
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").sendStatus(200);
});
```